# Gridview with grid inside with ItemClick

Tags: windows, gridview, styles, microsoft-metro

My ItemView_ItemClick is not executed when I click on a tile (except if I click on the rectangle selector).

Why ? How can I do that ? Thanks.

```
<GridView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <GridViewItem>
                <Grid Width="300" Height="200">
                    <Border Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                        <Image Source="{Binding SmallPic, Converter={StaticResource imageConverter }}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                    </Border>
                    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Opacity="1" Background="#7F000000" >
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource ItemContentStyle}" Foreground="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlayForegroundThemeBrush}"  Margin="15,0,15,0"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Price, Converter={StaticResource priceConverter }}" Foreground="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlaySecondaryForegroundThemeBrush}" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="15,0,15,10"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </GridViewItem>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

Comment: That's a pretty straightforward layout. What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: I succeed by doing this, but my event is not executed (see code in my first post)

Comment: curious - why do you have the <GridViewItem> element in your DataTemplate?  remove it and it works fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JimO'Neil it works. I put a gridViewItem because I thought that it was necessary for describe an item.

Answer (score 0):

Moving my comment to an answer....

The `<GridViewItem>` inclusion is unnecessary and seems to be causing the unwanted behavior.